# Is it possible to use time lagged variables in spurious regression?

Tags: time-series, correlation, stationarity, lags, spurious-correlation

Spurious regression is generated when we regress time series data that are non-stationary. So is it possible to time lag the variable to further find a higher correlation?

Answer (score 0):

Taking lagged non-stationary variable as a covariate in a regression model will result in spurious model as well, which will output an optimistically high biased value of `t-statistic` and `r squared`. This is because non-stationary time-series have very **long memory** as could be illustrated by an acf function plot.

Comment: What model can you recommend in these analysis of non-stationary variables so spurious model would be omitted? I am analyzing a commodity price and a stock price.

Comment: @chidori, a good choice is to take first differences of the time-series (returns). I specifically recommend log(xt) - log(xt-1) when it comes to stock data, which are unstationary in terms of variance of the returns.

Comment: So according to my research, ways to omit spurious results is to make the time series data stationary. If it exhibits a random walk, I need to use differencing and when it has a deterministic trend, I can detrend it. But if it fails, I'll analyze the returns instead (which what you have said). So when I examine the returns, do I assume it to be stationary? And what is the difference in normal returns and log(xt) - log(xt-1) and if it is unstationary, how do I correlate it?

Comment: @chidori, it is not necessary to detrend by substracting a trend model. You can take differences and the trend goes away. However, you can try to detrend, but then you don't take differences. **log(xt) - log(xt-1)** helps a lot when your returns are not stationary in variance.

Comment: What's the best correlation method for log returns?

Comment: @chidori, it is not a correct question. There is nothing best in statistics. Everything has its own limitations. Do you like the answer I gave to your initial question?

Comment: Okay i understand

Comment: I've decided to use cross-correlation of the log returns and lag them to see the highest correlation. Thank you